# "I will try to survive till that"

Tags: pronouns, demonstrative, demonstrative-pronouns

> I will try to survive till **that**.

My teacher (native) told me the THAT is not OK - and I have to find the good solution - this site is allowed.

Possibly I would formulate on the following way, but I'm not sure at all:

> I will try to survive till **that time**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"that time" is fine, but there is a more natural word:  "then". The word "then" can mean "that time"

> What time do you come home? / *6 pm* / I'll wait until then to do my homework because I want to ask you a question.

Comment: Of course, we say until that time, but until that is fine too. The OP did not specify exactly.

Comment: James, thanks for your answer, It is helpful, clear and understandable. Szabolcs

Answer (score -4):

Something will occur on **June 10th.**

I'll have to survive until **that**. [that is a pronoun replacing: June 10th].

You do not need to say: until that date or until that time. You can but it is not necessary **when speaking.**

SPOKEN ENGLISH

1. BBC NEWS:

"Not true," Cruise's spokesman said about the reports. "I can tell you that he never said **that**."
[BBC News](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/entertainment/4819826.stm)

2. CNN

Hicks’ lawyer denied that she ever said that in a statement to CNN.

“As most reporters know, it’s not my practice to comment in response to questions from the media,” said Robert Trout, a lawyer for Hicks. “But this warrants a response. **She never said that.** And the idea that Hope Hicks ever suggested that emails or other documents would be concealed or destroyed is completely false.”

[CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2018/01/31/politics/mark-corallo-hope-hicks-donald-trump-jr-emails)

3. They see rats all the time, and despite professing respect for their habitat, Kevin will often dispatch them into the flow with a whack from a bat he carries. “They can swim, but it’s so fast, **they won’t survive that**.”

Reprinted from "The Big Necessity," by Rose George. Copyright (c) 2008.
Reprinted with permission of the publisher, Metropolitan Books. All rights reserved.

Comment: If you want to replace a time with a pronoun you should use **then** (or **that time**), as James K describes.

Comment: @randomhead then is not a pronoun; it is an adverb.  As the English say "Mind how you go". So, you and the downvoters are **mistaken**.

Comment: Your examples show **that** being used as a pronoun to reference a *thing* (a purported statement, a fast-moving current). Using **that** to reference a *time* is not standard usage. Do you have such an example?

Comment: @randomhead We are so busy, it's crazy. The party is at 8 o'clock tonight. I guess I'll have to survive until that. [implied: time or event].

Comment: @randomhead The point is not time **necessarily** in the OP's first  formulation.  It could be an event. And as such is perfectly fine. Or even if "that" refers to an event occurring at some time.